# How to make JS data caching?

Tags: javascript

I am getting data from a paid API and it clearly states that I cannot save it, but I can cache it for 30 days. How can I make it so that when any user, from any device, could receive cached data?

Comment: Please include more details in the question.

Comment: Caching does not work like that. Caching is when a user comes to a site, and the site saves a version of that so that in the future when the user visits the site, it loads faster. You can cache the backend database using redis, but that's probably in the hands on the paid API, and you can't do much there.

Comment: Unless you create your own backend which fetches data from this "paid API", saves it to a database and you cache using redis. But this is probably not necessary

Comment: You can cache for single clients using [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localstorage). But this does not allow for sharing data between clients

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cache on backend. Frontend data cannot be shared between clients (frontends)